# Cloned a Time Machine backup but the clone has on somes file different permissions

Tags: backup, time-machine, permission, filesystem

I cloned a Time Machine backup folder `Backups.backupdb` from one volume to another following [Apple's instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202380). The contents of both folders look *very* similar (same amount of files, same file size, etc), so I assume the cloning worked well.

However, *some* files have different permissions listed when displayed with `ls -l`: A file `Info.plist` **on the original volume** shows like

```
-rw-r--r--@   1 extra  staff  13512 Jan  7  2015 Info.plist
```

while **on the cloned volume** it shows like

```
-rw-r--r--+   1 extra  staff  13512 Jan  7  2015 Info.plist
```

According to the macOS `ls` man page (I'm using OSX El Capitan) this means that **the original** (with **`@`** after the standard permission) has "*extended attributes*", while **the clone** (with **`+`** after the standard permission) has "*extended security information*". Clearly something is different.

What went wrong and how can I make a clone without these differences?

Comment: Which file systems do you have on the source and destination volumes?

Comment: @jksoegaard Both systems are "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)".